# How to fuzz service with sending bad data?

Tags: network, python

I am reading a post about [fuzzer](http://www.primalsecurity.net/0x3-python-tutorial-fuzzer/) in Python, here is the code:

```
# Import the required modulees the script will leverage
# This lets us use the functions in the modules instead of writing the code from scratch
import sys, socket
from time import sleep

# set first argument given at CLI to 'target' variable
target = sys.argv[1]
# create string of 50 A's '\x41'
buff = '\x41'*50

# loop through sending in a buffer with an increasing length by 50 A's
while True:
  # The "try - except" catches the programs error and takes our defined action
  try:
    # Make a connection to target system on TCP/21
    s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.settimeout(2)
    s.connect((target,21))
    s.recv(1024)

    print "Sending buffer with length: "+str(len(buff))
    # Send in string 'USER' + the string 'buff'
    s.send("USER "+buff+"\r\n")
    s.close()
    sleep(1)
    # Increase the buff string by 50 A's and then the loop continues
    buff = buff + '\x41'*50

  except: # If we fail to connect to the server, we assume its crashed and print the statement below
    print "[+] Crash occured with buffer length: "+str(len(buff)-50)
    sys.exit()
```

What confused me is why sending the data with an increasing length, or something like the code above, will crash the service?

Answer (score 1):

If the server has a poorly implemented buffer somewhere, it may cause a crash if the data exceeds what the buffer was initially set up to expect. In low level languages in C++, it is easy to set up poorly defined buffers this way, and a crash is good evidence that an exploitable error might exist.

https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Buffer_overflow_attack

(from the above)

```
 #include <stdio.h>
  int main(int argc, char **argv)
  {
  char buf[8]; // buffer for eight characters
  gets(buf); // read from stdio (sensitive function!)
  printf("%s\n", buf); // print out data stored in buf
  return 0; // 0 as return value
  }
```

If the actual input exceeds 8, there will be issues, although not necessarily a crash. This is a wide topic, but the most important thing to know is that if your service is crashing on large values, then you potentially have a security issue.